# SQL Server error in c# string or binary data will be truncated. insert statement conflict with foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
create table [User]
(
    userId int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key ,
    UserName nvarchar(30) unique,
    gender nvarchar(2),
    check( gender in ('M','F')),
    email nvarchar(40),
    DOB date
)

create table User_Auth
(
    uName nvarchar(30),
        foreign key (uName) references [User](UserName),
    pass nvarchar(30)
)

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CHECKREGISTERCREDENTIALSFORUSER]
    @USRNAME NVARCHAR(30),
    @DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE,
    @EMAIL NVARCHAR(50),
    @PASSWORD NVARCHAR(50),
    @GENDER NVARCHAR(5),
    @enterflag int output
AS
BEGIN
    SET @enterflag = 0;

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT UserName FROM [User] u WHERE u.UserName = @USRNAME)
    BEGIN
        IF (@DATE_OF_BIRTH <= GETDATE())
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [User] (UserName, gender, email, DOB) 
            VALUES (@USRNAME, @GENDER, @EMAIL, @DATE_OF_BIRTH)

            INSERT INTO [User_Auth] (uName, pass) 
            VALUES (@USRNAME, @PASSWORD)

            SET @enterflag = 1;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'invalid birth date entered';
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'username is taken';
    END
END
```

---

```
public static int Signup(string uname, string password, DateTime DOB, string email, string genders)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd;
    int result = 0;

    try
    {
        if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("CHECKREGISTERCREDENTIALSFORUSER", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@USRNAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = uname;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PASSWORD", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = password;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATE_OF_BIRTH", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DOB;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@GENDER", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 5).Value = email;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EMAIL", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = genders;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@enterflag", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@enterflag"].Value);
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SQL Error" + ex.Message.ToString());
        result = -1; //-1 will be interpreted as "error while connecting with the database."
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is the C# code - I can't figure out what is wrong - I get an error. There is not out of bound input in procedure parameters. Size of parameters in stored procedure is same as written in code. It is supposed to return 1 if sign up is successful. Moreover in my procedure I am adding into parent table and then to child table, still I get an error of

> Insert statement conflict with foreign key constraint

Comment: are you sure that the email ids you are passing are <= 50

Comment: Also, share your db schema

Comment: [DON'T store plain-text passwords](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/store-password-database/) ever!

Answer (score 1):

The values for `email` and `gender` are mixed around when you set the parameters, so you're actually setting the `email` value to the `gender` in the database and vice versa.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@GENDER", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 5).Value = email;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EMAIL", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = genders;
```

should be

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@GENDER", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 5).Value = genders;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EMAIL", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = email;
```

Additionally, in the `User` table `gender` is defined with length 2, but in the stored procedure it is declared length 5.  Yet, you use `check (gender in ('M', 'F'))` which is a single char.

If you're only accepting a single character for `gender`, you could update both the `User` table definition and stored proc to accept a single char for `gender`.